# Is there a way to force the immediate completion of a Storyboard?

Tags: wpf, events, animation, storyboard, code-behind

The gist of the code is

```
    Storyboard story = new Storyboard();
    DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation();
    anim.Completed += anim_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e);
    ...
    story.Children.Add(anim);
    story.Completed += story_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e);
    story.Begin(control, true);
return;
```

In another method I have:

```
    // Finish the Storyboard now
    story.SkipToFill(control);
    // I want it to get back to me here after the Completed events have run.
```

The problem is that the Completed events don't run until the next pass of the WPF dispatcher message loop which is no good to me because they update some state. I also tried

```
    story.Stop(control);
```

but then the Completed handlers don't get run at all it seems. Is there a way to get the Completed handlers to fire immediately?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid running your storyboard on another ui thread and handling locks or signals you can try the following:

```
Action emptyDelegate = delegate() { };
control.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, emptyDelegate);
```

...to force a render pass and hence pick up the completed events that don't seem to fire when you need them to during processing in the UI's code-behind.

You may see some artefacts come into and out of existence though as any updated dependency property values will, of course, be rendered.